# LESS not working in WordPress

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, child-theme

How to run the CSS preprocessor (LESS) in WordPress?

I'm trying to apply LESS in my child theme. I create `variable.less` and place it in the child theme folder `css/less/variable.less` and I call this .less in my style.css like this `@import "variable.less"`.

LESS is not working, I tried to call the js file for less in header and in the functions.php, but not of them are worked.

I checked the console, and there's an error `../css/less/variable.less 404 (Not Found)`. But the files is there.

I tried this in the header.php (child theme)

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/wp-content/themes/themename-child/css/less/variable.less" type="text/css" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

I tried this also... but no luck

```
function css_less(){
    wp_register_script('less-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/less.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('less-js');
    wp_register_style('less-css', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/less/variable.less');
        wp_enqueue_style('less-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_less');
```

style.css

```
.box-horizontal{ padding: 1em 2em 1em 2em; margin-top: -1em; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #CCC; box-shadow: @box-shadow; background: @bg-white; border-radius: 3px; }
.box-bg{ border: 1px solid #CCC; box-shadow: @box-shadow; background: #FFF; border-radius: 3px; text-align: center; }
```

Link: http://www.homecredit.ph/testEnvironment/mail-test/4830-2/

Comment: you need to fix your @import path

Comment: "not working" is not a question, it is a state. Please be specific about what you expect to happen that do not happen and describe as much of the relevant debuging effort as possible so people will not ask you about things you already tried.

Comment: And for enqueue script use get_stylesheet_directory_uri if you in child theme.

Comment: @Jevuska still not working :(

Comment: well, if you get 404 then either the file is not there, or you have problem with your server configuration

Comment: @MarkKaplun i added .less in mime type in my web service, but still not working

Comment: Why would someone compile LESS on the client side anyway? For a very small project it will be ok I guess but other than that it is a no go.

Comment: yup follow this http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage

Answer (score 1):

I agree with **@Zlatev** that you probably wouldn't want to do this clientside. There are easier ways to include less.

There are [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=less) that allow you to do this. Even jetpack has [less support](https://jetpack.com/support/custom-css/).

If your goal is to include this in your theme you can use [wp-less](https://github.com/oncletom/wp-less).

***Just download that plugin and drop in somewhere in your theme and include it in your `functions.php` like this:***

`require get_template_directory() . '/inc/wp-less/bootstrap-for-theme.php';`

***Then enqueue your less like normal css:***

```
function mytheme_enqueue_less_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style('official_flowershop-theme-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/less/theme.less');
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_less_css' );
```

***The plugin has lots of extra features you can use ([see full list here](https://github.com/oncletom/wp-less/tree/master/doc)):***

```
function mytheme_less_setup() {

    define('WP_LESS_COMPILATION', 'deep');
    $less = WPLessPlugin::getInstance();
    $less->dispatch();

    // do stuff with its API like:
    $less->addVariable('bg_primary', '#A0D4A4');
    $less->addVariable('bg_secondary', '#474747');
    $less->addVariable('bg_light', '#f5f5f5');
    $less->addVariable('bg_body', '#ffffff');

    if (get_theme_mod('officialtheme_bg_primary') != '' ) {
        $less_color = get_theme_mod("officialtheme_bg_primary");
        $less->addVariable("bg_primary", "$less_color");
    }

    if (get_theme_mod('officialtheme_bg_secondary') != '' ) {
        $less_color = get_theme_mod("officialtheme_bg_secondary");
        $less->addVariable("bg_secondary", "$less_color");
    }

    if (get_theme_mod('officialtheme_bg_light') != '' ) {
        $less_color = get_theme_mod("officialtheme_bg_light");
        $less->addVariable("bg_light", "$less_color");
    }

    if (get_theme_mod('officialtheme_bg_body') != '' ) {
        $less_color = get_theme_mod("officialtheme_bg_body");
        $less->addVariable("bg_body", "$less_color");
    } // WP Less initialize and add variables

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_less_setup' );
```

**Caution:**
While using less or sass/scss within a theme/plugin, as of now there aren't any available plugin solutions I'm aware of that let you prefix your css. To me this is a dealbreaker since I can do all of this on my computer with a program like [Prepros](https://prepros.io/) or Codekit.

However, you can do this clientside if you want pretty easily with [prefix-free](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/) although that's what we were previously trying to avoid so while it's easy, it's not necessarily a great solution.